# Kafka consumer keep on producing metadata.broker.list

Tags: apache-kafka

I am just executing some KafkaTestCases  on console. Zookeeper and Kafka brokers are started(I am seeing this in Ambari). There are 3 Zookeepers and 2 Kafka-Brokers are running.

I ran:

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list EdgeNodeAddress:xxxx --topic test21
```

(EdgeNodeAddress is the console where I am issuing the producer console command).

and I ran:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper zookeeperaddress:2181 --topic test21 --from-beginning
```

As soon as I ran the Kafka-Console-Consumer.sh script, it keeps on generating message like

> {metadata.broker.list=xxxxxxx2.xxxx:7903,xxxxxxxx2.xxxxxx:7903, request.timeout.ms=30000, client.id=console-consumer-1927, security.protocol=PLAINTEXT}

This message is keeps on generating until I stop it myself. It goes on like "while loop without meeting condition"

I troubleshooted zookeeper zkcli.sh to check if I could see the broker list(ls /brokers/ids) and it shows the broker ids [0,1]

I am not sure what is the issue.

Comment: Same behaviour on my cluster. I have a testing Kafka cluster managed by Ambari. The first time, I restarted Kafka using the Ambari UI, and it solved the problem, but today this behaviour persist and restarting didn't solved anything.

Comment: Same problem. Please let me know if you were able to resolve this. Some where I read that enabling kerberos causes this but my kafka setup does not have kerberos enabled.